# Manage custom posttype function using an additional menu in dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I have created a child theme for twenty-seventeen in wordpress and created a slider function to display slider images and also a custom post type for the function.
Now I created an extra menu under appearances in dashboard as Slider settings and I need to manage the slider using that settings.
In that settings I need to have the following

```
o   Enable slider option (check box)

o   Enable slider only for logged in users (check box)

o   Set a global title for slider block (text field)
```

I Added in back end but no condition added in front end to display slides based on this.

How could I do this?

Comment: Please show us the code you have attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code and change page for rendering options:

```
<?php
add_action('admin_menu', 'create_menu');

function create_menu() {
    add_options_page(__( 'Plugin Settings', 'textdomain' ),__( 'Plugin Settings', 'textdomain' ), 'administrator', __FILE__, 'settings_page', __FILE__);
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'mysettings' );
}


function mysettings() {
    register_setting( 'settings-group', 'enable_slider' );
    register_setting( 'settings-group', 'enable_slider_loggedin' );
    register_setting( 'settings-group', 'slider_title' );
}

function settings_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
    <h2><?php _e('PluginSettings','textdomain'); ?></h2>

    <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php settings_fields( 'settings-group' ); ?>
        <?php do_settings_sections( 'settings-group' ); ?>
        <table class="form-table">

            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row"><?php _e(' Enable slider','textdomain'); ?></th>
                <td>
                    <input name="enable_slider" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php checked( '1', get_option( 'enable_slider' ) ); ?> />
                    <p class="description"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row"><?php _e('Enable slider only for logged in users','textdomain'); ?></th>
                <td>
                    <input name="enable_slider_loggedin" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php checked( '1', get_option( 'enable_slider_loggedin' ) ); ?> />
                    <p class="description"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row"><?php _e('Title For Slider','textdomain'); ?></th>
                <td><input type="text" name="slider_title" value="<?php echo get_option('slider_title'); ?>" /></td>
            </tr>           
        </table>
        <?php submit_button(); ?>
    </form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Using like this:

```
if ( get_option ('enable_slider') == 1 ) {
// enable
} else {
//disable
}
```

Comment: how to link with these settings with the post type which I created??

Comment: this settings will save on wp_option and not dependent to post type.

Comment: I need to enable and disable one of my custom posttype and associated functionalities using the checkbox. So how could i do that?? Can u give your mail id please.